# Delete objects from Amazon S3 via Rails Aws API 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the s3_direct_upload gem to store images and videos on Amazon s3.  When the image or video is changed or deleted, I want to nuke the old image or video on s3 and save everyone money and space.

This solution uses the V1 Aws SDK and is no longer valid:

http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

This solution deletes files that were initially uploaded in a batch, but does nothing for the final files post-processing:

github - waynehoover/s3_direct_upload

Here is the Aws v2 SDK doc, which seems clear enough:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#delete_object-instance_method

Yet this solution:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :s3_image_file_url, :s3_image_file_path, :s3_image_file_key, presence: true

  before_destroy :delete_s3_files

  private
    def delete_s3_files
      s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new()
      response = s3.delete_object(
        bucket: Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket],
        key: self.s3_image_file_key
      )
    end
end
```

...returns only:

```
=> #<struct  delete_marker=nil, version_id=nil>
```

(And the file is still available on s3 at the original url.)

Thoughts?  Hasn't everyone had to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the bucket and key are correct?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

I've written code using the v2 SDK to delete objects from S3. Here is a sample from my codebase:

```
def delete_avatar_from_s3
  Aws::S3::Client.new.delete_object(
    bucket: "user-avatars",
    key: "#{@id}"
  )
  return true
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error "Error deleting avatar of user #{@id}. Failure with S3 call. Details: #{e}; #{e.backtrace}"
    return false
end
```

It looks similar to yours, so I don't think that this code is the issue. Have you confirmed your bucket & key names and ensured that your method is actually being called?

Answer (score 0):

**AWS SDK for Ruby V2**

delete one or more file, just pass `objects` array containing keys.

```
def delete_from_s3
 S3_BUCKET.delete_objects({
    delete: {
     objects: [
        {key: key}
        ]
      }  
    })
end
```